# PHP Countdown distribution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a randomized countdown that show number of products left in promotion alongside a timer. Number of products left is stored in the database, so all users see the same number. I am using simple php/ajax/javascript solution. My problem is with distributing the random sales so all fit within limited timer and are nicely distributed.

Here is code I have so far:

```
function start() {
    $date= new DateTime();
    $prod_left = getval("SELECT * FROM counter LIMIT 1");
    if ( $prod_left == 20 ) {
        $fp = fopen("../index.html", "r+");
        while($buf = fgets($fp)){
            if(preg_match("/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/", $buf)){
                fputs($fp, '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$(".countdown").circularCountdown({startDate:"' . $date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . '",endDate:"' . $date->modify("+5minutes")->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . '",timeZone:+2});});</script></body></html>');
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        sleep(30);
        while ($prod_left > 0) {
            if (rand(0,4) > 2) {
                $prod_left--;
                sleep(rand(1,13));
                updateval($prod_left);
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Promocja w trakcie lub zakończona, zresetuj zegar, jeżeli chcesz rozpocząć ponownie';
    }
    exit;
}
```

My assumption here is: 50% of time decrease timer and wait on average 6.5 seconds, which should on average give me 260 seconds for full sale. Unfortunately its very unevenly distributed. My goal is to have the sale completed not later than 270seconds after start. Will you be able to help?

Implementation doesnt need to be in any particular programing language, im just looking for a clue/concept I can follow to achieve this.

What is the strangest, the $prod_left value not always goes to 0, on sime iterations it just sits at 3 or 5.

Please help!

Comment: what is this for:

 **if (rand(0,4) > 2)**

using that is saying 50% of the times PHP excecutes the while it will do that, only resulting in a slower function.

Comment: by this I wanted to decrease the number of products left 50% on average, then giving average wait of 6.5s on each iteration **sleep(rand(1,13));** I wanted to achieve 260 seconds on average of total product countdown @KarsBarendrecht

Comment: right now if the number is higher than 2, it redoes the while loop, without timing out, so if it's wrong, it continues the same path within a second

Comment: so maybe better would be to make a loop with 260 iterations that each has 1 second delay and give 8% chance of decreasing product number?